# What is the name of this sci-fi series about man who crashes on earth in an alien ship after being abducted years earlier, returning w/ super powers?

Tags: story-identification, tv

It is about a man who crashes on earth in an alien ship. He had been abducted many years earlier and returned with super powers. For example, he hacks the CIA after quickly reading a programming book with his hands. He is on a mission to save the world but is constantly being hunted by the CIA. The main character is middle aged and has long hair.

What is the name of that series?

Comment: can you add any more production-level details: when did you see it? Where did you see it? What channel, what country, etc? Was it a long-running series, mini series, TV movie, etc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The  program was [The Visitor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118509/), broadcast from 1997-1998. It starred John Corbett. 50 years prior, he was abducted by aliens from the Bermuda Triangle. He escapes and returns to Earth in one of their ships, which he can still use to travel. The Aliens had experimented on him and activated the unused portions of his brain, allowing him to heal people as well as increased intelligence. The Army and the FBI are looking for him, the Army specifically as a threat. He travels around the country using his powers to help people. The Aliens are trying to find him and continue their experiments.

[image: The visitor cover, with shadowy man staring towards you]

Comment: The X-Files really had a lot to answer for.